# When run test case with ride get error"Robot Framework installation not found"and how to resolve this?

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

get error "robot framework installation not found" when run test case, but acturally i have already installed robot framework 3.1.2, why and how to resolve this problem?

i tried to uninstall robot framework 3.1.2 and install 3.1.1, but this did't work

i use:
mac os 10.14.5
python 3.7.3
robotframework 3.1.2
ride 1.7.3.1

1) get error"Robot Framework installation not found. To run tests, you need to install Robot Framework separately."

2) below is the ride log under tools->view ride log:

20190716 13:58:25.051 [INFO]: Found Robot Framework version 3.1.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot.
20190716 13:58:25.052 [INFO]: Started RIDE 1.7.3.1 using python version 3.7.3 with wx version 4.0.6 in darwin.
20190716 13:58:34.083 [INFO]: Robot Framework installation not found.
To run tests, you need to install Robot Framework separately.
See http://robotframework.org for
installation instructions.

3)below is the output log:

command: "no pybot" --argumentfile /var/folders/_s/jngzbhqx4pgf_n0t389c55hw0000gn/T/RIDEfnfngxmf.d/argfile.txt --listener /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robotide/contrib/testrunner/TestRunnerAgent.py:59252:False /Users/mac/Downloads/UIAutomation/TruckPath
unexpected error: /bin/sh: no pybot: command not found

i just run robot testcase.robot with command line, this work normally, this so strange!

Answer (score 0):

On newest RIDE and Robot Framework you should select `robot 3.1` from drop-down list in the Run tab.

Answer (score 0):

Upon selection of execution profile as robot 3.1, it is still showing the same error message as, 'Robot Framework installation not found.
To run tests, you need to install Robot Framework separately.
See http://robotframework.org for installation instructions'

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your bash_profile

1. Open terminal and type "open -e .bash_profile" without the quotes.
2. Copy paste the below commands at the end of the file-

PATH="/Users/***{your username}***/Library/Python/3.10/bin:${PATH}"

export PATH

PATH="/Users/***{your username}***/Library/Python/2.7/bin:${PATH}"

export PATH

3. Save the file and then restart ride.